# How to use multiprocessing package in Python?

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, signal-processing, python-multiprocessing

I have to calculate continuous wavelet transform of huge set of signals. For this purpose I use scipy.signal.cwt function. However, using of only one CPU takes a lot of time, that's why I wanna use all CPU's.

Here is convinient way:
(I create random signal only for reproducibility)

```
import numpy as np
import random
from scipy import signal

random.seed(0)
comp = 10
trace = np.zeros(1000)
t = np.linspace(0,1,1000)

for i in range(comp):
    frq = random.gauss(40,10)
    ampl = random.uniform(0,.01)
    fi = random.uniform(-np.pi,np.pi)
    comp_i = ampl*np.sin(2*np.pi*frq*t+fi)
    trace += comp_i

sampling_freq = 500 # Hz

def width(freq, sampling_freq):
    return sampling_freq*(2.0*np.pi*freq)**(-.5)

def cwt(f):
    cwt = signal.cwt(trace, signal.ricker, [width(i,sampling_freq)])
    return cwt

cwt_all = []

for i in range(1,81):
    cwt_i = cwt(i)
    cwt_all.append(cwt_i)
```

And that's how I use multiproccessing package:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

results = []

def collect_results(result):
    results.extend(result.tolist())
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count())
    for i in range(1,81):
        pool.apply_async(cwt, args=(i), callback=collect_results)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

And now it's running infinitely long and python doesn't use CPU.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: TL;DR but you missed the parentheses in the call to `pool.join()`.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you! 
But now it's running infinitely long and python doesn't use CPU :/

Comment: Your call to `apply_asynci` is incorrect; the *args* argument is wrong -- you are *not* passing a tuple. It should be: `pool.apply_async(cwt, args=(i,), callback=collect_results)`.

Comment: If you are running under Windows (and you are supposed to tag your question with your platform), all code you have at global scope will be executed by each process in the multiprocessing pool. This may not be the most efficient way to proceed. Moreover, each process will be initializing the random number generator identically.

Comment: Thank you, Booboo! But now it still doesn't work:(

Comment: I just saw your comment. If you want to write a comment and be sure that a user (such as myself) is notified of the new comment, then you need to precede the name of the user with an `@`, for example, @Kuando. or @Booboo. Anyway, I notice in function `cwt` the argument is `f`, but it is not used anywhere but you instead reference variable `i`,  whose value is not clear. And where is `cwt_all` being used? You should update your question with the latest source code as it now looks as one continuous code block.